Kriging climate data in R
I have this code to carry out kriging of climate data. I have 26 longitude and latitude points each with a corresponding temperature value.
Data:
df<-dput(weather_data)
structure(list(latitude = c(-5.66761223, -5.72480242, -5.71591633, 
-5.74702767, -5.718042, -5.70906367, -5.72364083, -5.6800395, 
-5.680813, -5.68343283, -5.69915, -5.72150967, -5.72126, -5.7480005, 
-5.68805267, -5.685108, -5.71851317, -5.713897, -5.7104425, -5.720915, 
-5.6980405, -5.74182587, -5.68076091, -5.77276449, -5.6662859, 
-5.74445058), longitude = c(-15.9421786, -15.9560469, -15.9541762, 
-15.9777202, -15.923983, -15.9396147, -15.945323, -15.9431937, 
-15.9449277, -15.9484998, -15.96467, -15.9544655, -15.96869, 
-15.996367, -15.9782928, -15.945571, -15.9378142, -15.9792287, 
-15.9235108, -15.9277867, -15.9728712, -15.9987156, -15.9206547, 
-16.0006466, -15.9819352, -15.9575332), tempmax = c(24.3, 23.1, 
24.4, 24.6, 35.7, 38.1, 34.6, 28.2, 32.6, 35.8, 37.7, 37.1, 38.6, 
36.1, 37.6, 36.2, 36, 41.2, 39.4, 32.9, 22.2, 33.2, 1, 23.7, 
17.5, 23.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -26L))

I have tried the code below however it has altered all my location points to the same longitude and latitude and outputs a map that is covered in pink with a value of 28.02807.
What causes this issue as I am looking for an output of a map with different temperatures shown across the area?
#output map is just fully pink with 16.88088C
#the kriging_df just has 651 values of 16.88088

# Load required packages
library(sp)      # For spatial data handling
library(gstat)   # For variogram and kriging
library(raster)  # For handling raster data in kriging output
library(ggplot2) # For visualization

#load in data
weather_data <- read.csv("weather.csv")

coordinates(weather_data)<-~longitude+latitude

#Create and fit a variogram for the chosen weather variable
# Replace `temperature` with your actual weather variable name (e.g., `precipitation`)
variogram_model <- variogram(tempmax ~ 1, data = weather_data)
fitted_model <- fit.variogram(variogram_model, model = vgm("Sph"))


#Define the extent of the map for St. Helena
lon_min <- -5.8
lon_max <- -5.6
lat_min <- -16.1
lat_max <- -15.8


#Set up the grid for interpolation (adjust extent as needed for your region)
lon_min <- min(lon_min)
lon_max <- max(lon_max)
lat_min <- min(lat_min)
lat_max <- max(lat_max)

# Create a grid for interpolation
# Adjust the 'by' value if needed (e.g., smaller value for higher resolution)
grd <- expand.grid(
  x = seq(lon_min, lon_max, by = 0.001),  # Longitude
  y = seq(lat_min, lat_max, by = 0.01)   # Latitude
)
coordinates(grd) <- ~x + y
gridded(grd) <- TRUE


#Perform kriging interpolation
kriging_result <- krige(tempmax ~ 1, locations = weather_data, newdata = grd, model = fitted_model)

#Convert kriging result to raster for visualization
kriging_raster <- raster(kriging_result)

# Convert raster to data frame for ggplot visualization
kriging_df <- as.data.frame(rasterToPoints(kriging_raster))
colnames(kriging_df) <- c("longitude", "latitude", "temperature")

# Plot the interpolated weather map
ggplot() +
  geom_raster(data = kriging_df, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, fill = temperature)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red", name = "Temperature (°C)") +
  labs(title = "Interpolated Temperature Map",
       x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude") +
  theme_minimal()


Output map from this code


I think you have reversed  the longitude and latitude somewhere.  Add geom_sf(data = weather_data |> sf::st_as_sf() )  to your ggplot and you will see the missmatch between the data and the krigging.
(I am more comfortable with sf, sorry to introduce an additionnal package)

You mixed the definition of the limits.  lon_min <- -5.8 should be the latitude:   lat_min <- -5.8 , and similarly for the lon_max lat_min and lat_max

If those points should be on Saint Helena, lat & lon in example data are indeed swapped. Just guessing from comments, but is this code generated by LLM? If yes and/or you don't actually care too much about sp & raster,  perhaps follow more recent example by gstat author, based on sf & stars - https://r-spatial.org/book/12-Interpolation.html

Hi @margusl Thank you for the help! I have been able to create a map that isn't entirely pink now. A lot of the code was generated through LLM. Just wondering what the difference of sp and raster or sf and stars? I am trying to get kriging done of different climate data and output as a raster for use in species distribution models

raster (the package) has been superseded by the terra; and sp "..\will (slowly) be deprecated .." in favor of sf.  stars and sf just use similar API.  You can freely convert between different raster objects.

Tl;dr: This answer addresses the issues with programming only!
Based on the link provided by user @margusl in comments below your question, this answer overcomes the issues described as

I have tried the code below however it has altered all my location points to the same longitude and latitude and outputs a map that is covered in pink with a value of 28.02807.

It also applies the kriging to the area of the island St. Helena, accessed with {osmdata}.
Disclaimer. This answer does neither comment on the chosen approach/models nor on the choices of parameters. Questions regarding those topics are best placed here, and considered off-topic on this site.
 # Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha
 library(osmdata)
 library(sf)
 library(ggplot2)
 
 # island boundaries 
 st_helena = getbb("St Helena", format_out = 'sf_polygon', featuretype = "country") |>
   _[["multipolygon"]]

 # load points, assumption: crs = 4326
 wd0_sf = st_as_sf(wd0, coords = names(wd0)[-3], crs = 4326)
 
 ggplot() + 
   geom_sf(data = st_helena) + 
   geom_sf(data = wd0_sf, mapping = aes(col = tempmax)) +
  scale_color_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red", name = "Temperature (°C)") +
  labs(title = "Temperature Map", subtitle = "St. Helena",
       x = "Latitude", y = "Longitude") +
  theme_minimal()


Create grid and apply kriging.
 library(stars) 
 grd = 
   st_bbox(st_helena) |>
   st_as_stars(dx = .001) |>
   st_crop(st_helena) 
 
 v = variogram(tempmax ~ 1, wd0_sf)
 vm = fit.variogram(v, vgm(2, "Exp", 1, 1))
 k = krige(tempmax ~ 1, wd0_sf, grd, vm)
 #> [using ordinary kriging]
 
 ggplot() + 
   geom_stars(data = k, aes(fill = var1.pred, x = x, y = y)) + 
   geom_sf(data = st_cast(st_helena, "MULTILINESTRING")) + 
   geom_sf(data = wd0_sf) + 
   scale_fill_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red", name = "Temperature (°C)") +
   labs(title = "Interpolated Temperature Map", subtitle = "St. Helena",
        x = "Latitude", y = "Longitude") +
   theme_minimal()



Note
Point locations as provided in question.
 wd0 = structure(list(latitude = c(-5.66761223, -5.72480242, -5.71591633, 
                                   -5.74702767, -5.718042, -5.70906367, -5.72364083, -5.6800395, 
                                   -5.680813, -5.68343283, -5.69915, -5.72150967, -5.72126, -5.7480005, 
                                   -5.68805267, -5.685108, -5.71851317, -5.713897, -5.7104425, -5.720915, 
                                   -5.6980405, -5.74182587, -5.68076091, -5.77276449, -5.6662859, 
                                   -5.74445058), longitude = c(-15.9421786, -15.9560469, -15.9541762, 
                                                               -15.9777202, -15.923983, -15.9396147, -15.945323, -15.9431937, 
                                                               -15.9449277, -15.9484998, -15.96467, -15.9544655, -15.96869, 
                                                               -15.996367, -15.9782928, -15.945571, -15.9378142, -15.9792287, 
                                                               -15.9235108, -15.9277867, -15.9728712, -15.9987156, -15.9206547, 
                                                               -16.0006466, -15.9819352, -15.9575332), tempmax = c(24.3, 23.1, 
                                                                                                                   24.4, 24.6, 35.7, 38.1, 34.6, 28.2, 32.6, 35.8, 37.7, 37.1, 38.6, 
                                                                                                                   36.1, 37.6, 36.2, 36, 41.2, 39.4, 32.9, 22.2, 33.2, 1, 23.7, 
                                                                                                                   17.5, 23.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -26L))


names(wd0)[-3] : I also found myself wondering how to approach and handle faulty names in input data. Here we can also use numeric col indices, st_as_sf(coords = 1:2, ...)

@margusl, thank you. I try to avoid passing columns by integer indexing. A good routine would be to write out/pass the character names or check names(wd0)[-3] in a previous step I think. For good golfing, I sometimes do X[-1] or similar.
